# Domain of convergence for a Laurent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

The Laurent series I have is given as $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} \frac{z^n}{|n-2|^3} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{(2n)!}$$ I was trying to figure out the interval of convergence for the second half, I know how to do the first half, but on the second half, I tried the ratio test and the limit ends up going to $0$ which means the test is inconclusive, what can I do with the second half to find the radius of convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second sum I get $r=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\dfrac1{\sqrt[n]{\dfrac1{2n!}}}=\infty$.

Since the first part converges for $|z|\gt1$, that will also be where the whole thing does.

Comment: Gotcha okay I wasn't sure on that part, but I figured the root test here would work.

Comment: I used  Cauchy-Hadamard.  Doesn't the root test work too?  If the ratio goes to zero, then it converges everywhere.

Comment: oh, well, the root test in my text just states that the radius of convergence can be found by $$R= \frac{1}{\limsup\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty} |a_k|^{\frac{1}{k}}}$$.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up ratio and root.  But the ratio test appears to work.

Comment: Doesn't the ratio test say that we have $$\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$$?

Comment: Yes.  But don't we get zero?  So it converges everywhere.

Comment: Yes but when the ratio test is $0$ its inconclusive right?

Comment: No, that's when it's $1$.

Comment: That explains this whole post haha, I forgot that one fact, I thought if it was 0 it was inconclusive, this simplifies so much haha thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Sure thing. @Joey.